# Python3 Script Not Running When Executed From Icon On Rasbpian Desktop

Tags: python-3.x, terminal, raspberry-pi3, raspbian, execute

I'm newer to Linux and Python3.
I am creating an RFID reader and have a script that works. 
If I execute the .py script using terminal commands, it runs perfect, but if I double click the .py file in the folder and click "Execute in Terminal" it gives me a blank terminal screen. My script does not run. 
Here's what I have already tried:

1.In Terminal:

```
~/Desktop/RFID_FILES/chmod +x RFID_READER.py
```

2.Top line of my .py script:

```
 #!/usr/bin/python3
```

3.I even tried making an icon to execute the script:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=RFID Control
Exec=/home/pi/Desktop/RFID_FILES/RFID_READER.py
Terminal=true
```

Same result when launching from this icon.

This is what I get when double clicking the .py file or icon. 
[Blank_Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZ41j.jpg)

The title is shown "RFID_READER.py", but the script doesn't run, and I can't even type anything.
It should start by printing "What would you like to do?"

Again, this script works if executed through the terminal using `Python3 RFID_READER.py`

So, what do I need to change in order to double click my icon and have the script actually run in the terminal? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum, it is a Question and Answer site where you can ask a **specific** programming question that **can be answered** rather than discussed. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and then edit your question to conform with the site guidelines. Off-topic questions such as this one are routinely closed, but if edited to ask an *answerable* question, can be re-opened again. Thanks.

Comment: I thought my problem was fairly clear. I can't get the script to run correctly. I need to know what I've done wrong or haven't done. I can't be the only person to experience this.

Comment: That's better. Originally there was no question being asked, which makes it hard for anyone to be able to reply. It would be even better if you could provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so others can help to diagnose the problem. I don't know much about python, but it doesn't look like you have enough code in your question so that others can reproduce the problem. And if the problem is with your code, finding the minimal code to reproduce it could provide a valuable clue to fixing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured a way around this by using a shell script. 
Instead of having my icon call the program directly, I have my icon call a shell script which initiates

```
~/Desktop/RFID_FILES/ python3 READER.py
```

This allows the application to open without issue. 
I still can't explain exactly why I can't open the application directly, but creating a .sh file and then calling that file with the icon works.